# How to anchor floor lags with concrete slab

Tags: wood, floor, slab

I have the apartment with the floor build from wooden lags on concrete slab. The concrete slab is hollow slab 220mm height that is both ceiling of the downstairs neighbours. Wooden lags are now disassembled.

The concrete slab has a slope up to 5-10cm. Also the surface of the slab is rugged: with holes and hills.

Now I need to build a new floor with wooden lags, plywood and parquet. The first layer is vibration mount (like a metal profile with height regulation possibility up to 2cm). The second layer is wooden beam, aligned with 50 cm step. The third and fourth layers are plywood.

I don't want to anchor vibration mounts (lags) and slab with dowels or metal anchors (don't want to drill slab). Can I anchor vibrations mounts with glue (that is called liquid nails) and wooden spacers? Or can I anchor and align by height with cement mix (or tile adhesive)? Finally, do I need to to anchor lags and slabs?

Vibration mounts:

[image: vibration mounts]

Common photo of the concrete slabs:

[image: photo of the slabs]

Example of the expected result:

[image: Example of expected wooden lags]

Comment: Answering this question would require an expert who is informed of the details of the vibrations you wish to isolate the floor from. Did you choose these vibration dampers or are they commonly used in your locality? Do you know what is the expected service life of these dampers? Which country and city is this bldg located in?

Comment: adhesicve is not going to work on a loose or dusty surface,  you'll probably need a strong adhesive like epoxy.

Comment: @JimStewart, I have no details about floor or slab vibrations. Wooden floors are not commonly used in St Petersburg (Russia) now, so this damper is the only choice that I have found at market.

Comment: My sister lived in a house on continually wet, high organic soil in New Orleans, Louisiana USA that was on a busy street. When heavy trucks would go by the floor of the house would undulate. Is this the source of the vibrations in the building in this question?

Comment: The described environment conditions are very similar to local ones. But the main reason for using the dampers (and other upper-layer solutions) is to isolate apartment noise from downstairs neighbours. Street noise isn't a problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

If the purpose of this proposed construction is blocking sound transmitted through the ceiling of the apartment below and through the floor of your apartment, then there should be a rich literature on this subject.

Without any personal experience in this field, I question whether these elastomer connectors/isolators  would be effective for blocking sound. Furthermore, they likely would not be able to support the static and dynamic load of the floor and contents. If (when) they would fail, replacement would be a nightmare.

Just looking at them, they would appear to be intended as vibration isolators for machinery. I can imagine them being used to support a platform on which a person would doing jumping exercises such as jumping a rope. This might reduce the vibration/sound transmitted to the apartment below, but not to the one above.